# Drush set block setting only working for one value

Tags: drush

If I disable the powered by block, and use drush to enable it, the block shows back up again. I use:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/drupal# drush config-get 
block.block.bootstrap_powered status
'block.block.bootstrap_powered:status': false

root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/drupal# drush config-set 
block.block.bootstrap_powered status true
Do you want to update status key in block.block.bootstrap_powered config? (y/n): y
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/drupal# drush config-get 
block.block.bootstrap_powered status
'block.block.bootstrap_powered:status': true

root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/drupal#
```

However, disabling doesn't work and the block continues to show:

```
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/drupal# drush config-set         
block.block.bootstrap_powered status false
Do you want to update status key in block.block.bootstrap_powered config? (y/n): y
root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/drupal# drush config-get 
block.block.bootstrap_powered status
'block.block.bootstrap_powered:status': true

root@vagrant-ubuntu-trusty-64:/var/www/drupal#
```

Thoughts on what I'm doing wrong here? Using Drupal 8.

Answer (score 0):

Ended up having to use:

```
drush config-set block.block.bootstrap_powered status --value=''
```

Comment: Doesn't `drush config-set block.block.bootstrap_powered status 0` work?